# GitHub VCS not showing in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio

In version control systems GitHub is not showing in the menus of Android Studio Ver. 2.2.1. So now I cant share any of my projects on GitHub. I uninstalled the GitHub app from my PC, not sure if that is the reason why it is gone from Android Studio. I reinstalled the app but still nothing. I attached some photos to show what I mean.

[image: Share Project On GitHub not showing up]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have to initialize an empty git repo first.

Comment: Umm. There is a "Git" menu option in your picture there. Git is the tool, Github is a website that hosts Git repositories. The IDE won't just say "Github"

Answer (score 6):

You should have `GitHub` plugin enabled. It could be enabled at `Settings (Ctrl+Alt+S) -> Plugins`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It saves my time